# Media query min-width not considering devices below a certain width

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, device

Why is some devices NOT listening to my media query when the device width is smaller than "375" which is my smallest breakpoint. I use @media (min-width: 375px) { // Rules here }... I get that it "requires" that the device has to be at least "375px" wide, but I can't figure out what's wrong here. It works when I change the 375-breakpoint to 0px... But is that even a correct approach?

In my "media.scss" file, I've it all set up like this:

```
@media (min-width: 375px) {}
@media (min-width: 768px) {}
@media (min-width: 992px) {}
@media (min-width: 1280px) {}
```

Everything works fine, but when testing on a device that is smaller than 375 pixels, it doesn't consider the rules. I hope you get what I mean. I've looked how bootstrap has their media queries, and I can't really tell if there is any difference.

Comment: You should use default styles first then the media queries to override those default styles, if you have put your default in the first media query, then the elements won't be styled when the browser is under 375px

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/ayo2wfup/1/.  If this is not what you meant then please edit your question with a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter if you use the mobile-first or desktop-first approach, you need some styles that apply when *none* of the media queries apply. In your example, there are *no* styles which apply for widths below 375px. Most likely it would be okay if you simply take the CSS rules you have inside the first query (<375) out of that query and put it at the very beginning of the stylesheet.

Or said differenty: Just erase the `@media (min-width: 375px) {` at the beginning and its closing `}` bracket, then those styles will apply to all widths below 768px  (also to those narrower than 375px)

Answer (score -1):

Create a media query with max-width: 374px and insert your css into it.